# Software for normalization in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, database-normalization

I know that decomposing relations into Boyce-Codd Normal Form (BCNF) is done by an algorithm.

If it's done by an algorithm, I wonder if there exists software to do the decomposing for me? I know how to do but I often tend to do some stupid mistakes and I want to be completely sure that I made it correct.

Answer (score 0):

Normalization absolutely is used in the real world... and hopefully you know that 3NF is only the third one of... what is is now, 8? But 3NF should be an easy target.

However... I would venture to say that there could not be such a tool.

Normalization, technically, is an attribute of each table. Within a given database, different tables may have different levels of normalization.

Each table represents facts... facts about instances of a certain type of thing (person, account, order, shipment, item, location) including, sometimes, foreign keys which lead you to other kinds of facts about that thing.

Normalization has to do with how precisely the tables represent the facts and now well the table's design can prevent misrepresentation or inconsistent representation of the facts.

Thus,

> **an understanding of the actual facts is required... which is outside the scope of automated tools**

.

Read more about it [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24748/is-there-a-tool-to-check-if-my-database-is-normalized-to-the-third-normal-form) at the original post.